# Is it possible to calculate basic indicators such as precision, accuracy, recall and f-1 score based on Levenschtein distance?

Tags: python-3.x, ocr

In the context of OCR, I will try to summarize my problem:

1. I have ground truth sentence and OCR output:

- ground truth: THAIICEDCOFFEE1@22.00022.000SUB-TOTAL22.000GRANDTOTAL22.000CASH22.000CHANGED0
- OCR output: THAIICEDCOFFEE022.000SUB-TOTALGRANDTOTAICASHCHANGED22.ooo22.00022100022

2. I calculated Levenshtein distance, in this case it will be 39.
3. Depending on Levenshtein distance I calculated CER. In this case is 0,50.
4. Can I use calculated Levenshtein distance to get other's indicators like Precision, Accuracy, Recall and F-1 score? If not how can I do this based only on the real text and the one that OCR returns to me?

I tried to get TP (True Positive), TN (True Negative), FP (False Positive), FN (False Negative) measures but in this case I don't know how to classify these measures either..

Can anyone give me example how correct obtain OCR indicators depending on real text and output from OCR?